# Return a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need help making this function after taking an array and another array (duplicate) that has just the numbers that are duplicated in the first array (for example `array=[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,6]`, `duplicate=[1,2,3,6]`).

I want it to return an array as follow: `finalArray1=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],4,5,[6,6]]`.

```
let input = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

let sortArray = array => {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;});
}

function findDuplicates(data) {

  let duplicate = [];

  data.forEach(function(element, index) {

    // Find if there is a duplicate or not
    if (data.indexOf(element, index + 1) > -1) {

      // Find if the element is already in the duplicate array or not
      if (duplicate.indexOf(element) === -1) {
        duplicate.push(element);
      }
    }
  });

  return duplicate; 
}

let newArray = (array, duplicate) => { 

  for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    for( var j = 0; j < 15; j++ ){
      if( duplicate[i] == array[j] ){
        let finalArray = new array().push(array[j]);
      }
    }
    return finalArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `duplicate` also have `6`? And : you never call the function `findDuplicates`. What if original has a value that occurs 3 times? Will `duplicates` have unique values still? How will this affect the output?

Comment: do you need an ordered result?

Comment: yeah my bad i'll edit that. Use can use console.log to see results but it doesnt work. I have some issue with the last function

Comment: no i already do the ordered result and find the duplicates, I just need help with the last function to put them all in separate arrays within the same array

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and return in original order.

The map takes the items in insertation order, which means all item are later in original order. If a key exists, it createsd an array with the value. Otherwise just the item form the array is taken as value for the map.

At the end take only the values from the map and create an array of it.

```js
let input = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20],
    result = Array.from(input
        .reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, m.has(v) ? [].concat(m.get(v), v) : v), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

A more traditional approach

```js
let input = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20],
    result = input
        .sort((a, b) => a -b)
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            if (a[i - 1] !== v && v !== a[i + 1]) r.push(v); // check if unique
            else if (a[i - 1] !== v) r.push([v]);            // check left element
            else r[r.length - 1].push(v);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!! lol i was working on this since last night and you did it in 5lines.

Comment: could you just explain what you did on the result please

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can work for you:

```js
const input = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

const inOrder = input.sort((a, b) => a - b);
const unique = inOrder.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.includes(c));      
  if (found) found.push(c);
  else a.push([c]);      
  return a;
}, []);
const result = unique.map(e => e.length > 1 ? e : e[0]);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I'll go over it and if i dont understand something and i'll let you know if you dont mind

Comment: @Ali Sure, happy to help!